# Is there any existing software which can read the data from LCD screen via camera and put it to CSV or any other machine readable format?

Tags: ocr, data, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

For example, I have cheap 1 euro Chinese thermometer like this

[image]

and I want to make a graph of the temperature depends on the time of the day. This cheap device does not have any integration with PC/Phone, no USB input/output, no Bluetooth, nothing. It has just battery and a digital screen.

Ideally, I would like to point the web camera to this device and get the data as CSV or text format table with 2 columns (datetime and temperature) with predefined time intervals like every 10 seconds. Is there any software/website which can do this via OCR or Artificial Intelligence/Machine Learning? I tried to use some web-based OCR and it does not work well for this kind of device and also it can do OCR of 1 image, not the interval OCRing.

Of course, I can buy the device which can give me a nice graph, data in any format via Bluetooth/wifi/USB Cable, etc., but it will cost like 50$ and I do not want to spend this money :) Yes, I want to spend 1$ and get the same results as for 50 :) Webcam and PC I already have.

Another reason, that I want to have a generic solution, which will work with most of the devices, that I do not need to buy 50$ device every time I want to measure something. Today I need a temperature, tomorrow I will need humidity, after tomorrow maybe voltage in 230 V socket and see if it changing over the day to complain to the electricity provider, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) (to get the image and perform initial processing of it to do things like text localisation) and possibly OCR (e.g. [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)) to convert the text to any format that you desire. I would recommend using [python](https://www.python.org/) as the glue to stick all of these together and to output to CSV *(it has a library for that of course)*.

There are even tutorials available online for how to do exactly this sort of thing, e.g.:

- [Recognizing digits with OpenCV and python](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/) walks you though reading an electricity meter from a fixed angle.
- [OpenCV OCR and text recognition with Tesseract](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/) walks you through spotting and processing text within images.

All of the above software is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Available for most platforms

Comment: Yes, This is what I thought. I have to do it myself.